# If statement with two jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, if-statement

I'm trying to get an alert to appear if two conditions are met:

- The value of the `display` property on the `#playerbox` element is `block`, AND
- The value of the `display` property on the `#playerinfo` element is `none`

I have this:

```
if ($("#playerbox").css("display") == "block" && $("#playerinfo").css("display") == "none"){
    alert("test");
}
```

But the alert never appears. However, testing just one element will work:

```
if ($("#playerbox").css("display") == "block"){
    alert("test");
}
```

So I'm assuming I'm not chaining the two selectors together correctly in the `if` statement. What am I doing wrong?

---

UPDATE: I should have specified that `#playerinfo` is *inside* `#playerbox`. Does that change anything?

Comment: Have you also separately tested: `$("#playerinfo").css("display") == 'none'`?

Comment: Oops, misread the question. Answer deleted.

Comment: Your code seems to work on its own: http://jsfiddle.net/s3Ze9/ (click anywhere to test). Maybe you should `alert` or `console.log` the values before the `if` statement runs to see if you are getting what you expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use `:visible` and `:hidden`?

```
if ($("#playerbox:visible,#playerinfo:hidden").length == 2){
     ...
}
```

Comment: It works, but so does the OP's code: http://jsfiddle.net/s3Ze9/ (click anywhere to test)

Comment: Turns out the problem was with something else in my script, but Ori's code is cleaner and shorter than mine anyway. I'll take it anyway :-)

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you JQuery actually found the elements you are looking for?

```
alert($("#playerbox").length);

alert($("#playerinfo").length);
```

if either of those are coming back as 0, then you aren't really getting those elements. Maybe you are have a typo, or the class name set rather than the id.

Comment: Good answer. If no element is selected then `.css()` will return `undefined`, for example: `$('#doesnt-exist').css('display')` will return `undefined`. And `undefined == "none"` will always resolve to false.

Answer (score 0):

Use `is`

For example

```
 if($("#playerinfo").is(":hidden")) /* :visible for your other selector */
       //do stuff
```

Comment: It works, but so does the OP's code: jsfiddle.net/s3Ze9 (click anywhere to test)